# Nodejs regexp error: "Invalid regular expression: nothing to repeat"

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

So I have this regular expression:

```
(?:[ \t]*)?(?:\/\/|\/\*)[ \t]*#exclude[ \t]*([^\n*]*)[ \t]*(?:\*\/)?(?:[ \t]*[\r\n]+)?((?:.|\n|\r)*?)(?:[ \t]*)?(?:\/\/|\/\*)[ \t]*#endexclude[ \t]*(?:\*\/)?(?:[ \t]*[\r\n]+)?
```

Which is supposed to match anything that looks like this:

```
/* #exclude */
hurdur = somerandomtextorcode;
/* #endexclude */
```

I am trying this regular expression in tools such as https://regex101.com/ (https://regex101.com/r/eA5oK9/1) and there it just simply works, no errors.

However, in the nodejs environment, I get this error which I really do not know how to solve:

```
Warning: Invalid regular expression: /(?:[      ]*)?(?://|/*)[  ]*#exclude[
]*([^
]*)[    ]*(?:*/)?(?:[   ]*[
]+)?((?:.|
|
)?)(?:[         ]*)?(?://|/*)[  ]*#endexclude[  ]*(?:*/)?(?:[   ]*[
]+)?/: Nothing to repeat Use --force to continue.
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like `\t` and `\n` have been taken literally. Are you using `new Regexp` by chance?

Comment: Yes, I am using 
`new RegExp('(?:[ \t]*)?(?:\/\/|\/\*)[ \t]*#exclude[ \t]*([^\n*]*)[ \t]*(?:\*\/)?(?:[ \t]*[\r\n]+)?((?:.|\n|\r)*?)(?:[ \t]*)?(?:\/\/|\/\*)[ \t]*#endexclude[ \t]*(?:\*\/)?(?:[ \t]*[\r\n]+)?', 'gi')`

to create the regular expression. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yep, it turns `\n` into literal line breaks. Either use a regex literal `/.../`, or double all backslashes, i.e. `\\n` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it turns out it was a problem related to the way I was actually *creating* the regular expression.

I was creating (and applying) the regular expression like this:

```
var rExclude = '(?:[ \t]*)?(?:\/\/|\/\*)[ \t]*#exclude[ \t]*([^\n*]*)[ \t]*(?:\*\/)?(?:[ \t]*[\r\n]+)?((?:.|\n|\r)*?)(?:[ \t]*)?(?:\/\/|\/\*)[ \t]*#endexclude[ \t]*(?:\*\/)?(?:[ \t]*[\r\n]+)?';

contents = contents.replace(new RegExp(rExclude, 'gi'), function () { return ""; });
```

This gives me the error that is described in the starting post.
However, because the regular expression is in a *string*, JavaScript decides it wants to handle the regular expression differently. You can fix it in two ways:

**Solution 1**
This solution alters the way stuff is being escaped in your string.

```
var rExclude = '(?:[ \t]*)?(?://|/\\*)[ \t]*#exclude[ \t]*(?:\\*/)?(?:.|\n|\r)*?(?://|/\\*)[ \t]*#endexclude[ \t]*(?:\\*/)?';

contents = contents.replace(new RegExp(rExclude, 'gi'), function () { return ""; });
```

**Solution 2**
This solution alters the way the actual regular expression is being created:

```
contents = contents.replace(/(?:[ \t]*)?(?:\/\/|\/\*)[ \t]*#exclude[ \t]*(?:\*\/)?(?:.|\n|\r)*?(?:\/\/|\/\*)[ \t]*#endexclude[ \t]*(?:\*\/)?/gi, function () { return ""; });
```

It's just another weird ass JavaScript quirk, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Double-up your backslashes.

Notice how here: `(?:*/)?` there's no backslash? This means your `*` is trying to repeat.. nothing. Nothing to repeat.

Comment: This is not the solution. That specific part:
    (?:*/)?
is from the error string. All characters are parsed through nodejs already, so you don't notice that I actually /do/ escape that specific asterisk.

See the actual regex string to see that I am actually doing that :p